# can the arithmetic genus of a smooth projective surface be arbitrary?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Can the arithmetic genus of a smooth projective surface be arbitrary integer ?

The surfaces in $\mathbb P^3$ always have nonegative $g_a$ (it's $0$ if $1 \leq d \leq 3$ and $\binom{d-1}{3}$ if $d \geq 4$), so I wonder whether $g_a$ can be other values, in particular less than $-1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X = C \times \mathbb{P}^1$ then 
$$
g_a(X) = \chi(\mathcal{O}_X) - 1 = (1 - g(C)) - 1 = -g(C),
$$
so it can take arbitrary non-positive values.

Comment: Thank you, do you know what the value can be if we restrict to those surfaces that are not product of curves (or their blow up)?

Comment: A ruled surface over a curve $C$ also has $g_a$ equal to $-g(C)$.

Comment: Thank you again, how about all positive values?

Comment: Try products of curves.

Comment: the products of curves only gives $(2-2g_1)(2-2g_2)-1$, this is always an odd integer...?

Comment: You seem to confuse holomorphic and topological Euler characteristics.

Comment: Thank you again！I make the mistake as you said... I think your anwser is perfect. If we rule out those example coming from product or fibrations on curves, can we produce example using knowledges of surfaces？For instance, a surface must have nonegative \chi if it can be embedded into an abelian variety...